# Which version of git is used in TFS 2015 and VSTS

Tags: git, azure-devops, tfs-2015

Which version of Git is being used under the hood for TFS 2015 and VSTS? Git v2.8 has an interesting feature that I'd like to use, but I'n sure how it will be supported.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the feature?

Comment: Submodules mainly, although I think that's been around since before 2.8, and parallel fetching submodules (new with 2.8).

Comment: Cool, those are all Git client-side changes, so you should be able to use Git 2.8 on your machine to get parallel fetching of submodules when talking to TFS 2015/VSTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS and VSTS support Git service, you need to install Git v2.8 on your local machine to work with TFS/VSTS.